# Simular background-size:cover con imagen en línea usando sólo CSS

Tags: css, css3

Estoy trabajando en una página web en la que **no puedo cambiar la estructura HTML y no puedo usar JavaScript**. Sólo puedo hacer cambios en el CSS.

La idea es que haya una sección *hero* en la que el cliente subirá una imagen que se pondrá en línea (con la etiqueta `img`) y quiere que sea responsiva. El alto será fijo (425px) y el ancho será variable (ajustándose a un % fijo de la pantalla).

Idealmente pondría la imagen como fondo del `div` principal y le pondría `background-size:cover` para que se ajustara automáticamente al tamaño del contenedor. Pero estoy limitado al HTML proporcionado.

Éste es el código que tengo hasta ahora (simplificado, pero es lo que hay):

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

#hero {
  height:425px;
  width:75%;
  float:left;
}

#hero div, #hero p {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#hero img {
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  transform:translate(0, -12.5%);
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/900x520" alt="Gato" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El código de arriba funciona más o menos, pero no me termina de convencer porque la imagen no acaba centrada y el -12.5% del `trasnform:translate` es un número *mágico* que encontramos hacía que no se quedaran espacios en blanco. NOTA: **la imagen puede cambiar de tamaño**, siempre tendrá una proporción parecida, pero a veces será más grande y otras veces más pequeña.

¿Hay alguna manera de simular el comportamiento del `background-cover` pero en lugar de con una imagen de fondo, con una imagen en línea?

Comment: ¿No puedes añadir ninguna clase al css?

Comment: El CSS lo puedo cambiar como quiera. Lo que no puedo cambiar es el HTML (ni añadir JS)

Comment: Al HTML quería decir jajaja

Comment: Después de ocupar el 75%, el alto también tendría que seguir siendo 425px? Ya que si el objetivo es que sea responsive, la imagen se tendrá que hacer más pequeña de altura también. Me refiero a cuando mueves la pantalla.

Comment: El alto será siempre 425px. Tiene estilos diferentes para tableta y móvil (que no he incluido en la pregunta porque no son relevantes) en la que ocupará un 100% del ancho con altura automática. Pero para pantalla grande el alto estará fijo a 425px (porque en el 25% restante hay un scroller con datos)

Comment: Pero imagínate que haces la pantalla más pequeña hasta que ocupe 200px. La imagen va a quedar super estirada hacia abajo. Supongo que 425px será simplemente el contenedor no?

Comment: Tiene estilos diferentes para tableta y móvil (que no he incluido en la pregunta porque no son relevantes) en la que ocupará un 100% del ancho con altura automática. En esos casos se verá diferente. Sólo me interesa el caso de la pantalla grande, que es el que he compartido.

Comment: Te pongo una respuesta y me dices si es lo que quieres. Si no, no tengo ningún problema en editarla y en hacer una nueva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras probar varios ejemplos, que he encontrado, y ninguno ha funcionado al 100%, he podido crear un *simulador* `background-size:cover`.

En los dos ejemplos he dejado el HTML original.

**Primera** *(y verdadera)* **opción** :

**[Ver Demo 1 simular background-size:cover](http://output.jsbin.com/yisage)**

```
p {
  position: relative; 
  top: 0; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%;
  height: 425px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**Segunda opción:**

Es con `object-fit: cover;` lo único malo es que no esta soportado en [Internet Explorar](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).

**[Ver Demo 2 con object-fit](http://output.jsbin.com/rewame)**

```
img {
  width: 100vw;
  height:425px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: La primera opción es más lo que buscaba. La segunda opción no funciona bien cuando el contenedor `hero` tiene un ancho del 75% (aunque se puede solucionar fácilmente poniéndole un `width:75vw` a la imagen)

Comment: hmmm... misterio del voto negativo...

Comment: Parece que alguien ha votado negativo ambas respuestas. La verdad no sé por qué

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Si de eso me he dado cuenta también, lo dicho, queda misterioso

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro El misterio de los votos negativos sin explicación. Con lo poco que cuesta dejar un breve comentario constructivo, al menos aprenderíamos algo más ^^

Answer (score 0):

El width al 75% no te lo está cogiendo porque está intentando hacer el 75% de la anchura del elemento padre, es decir, del body, y como este no tiene una anchura definida por eso no te hace el 75% de la imagen. Ponle al body una anchura fija o `width: 100%` y ya te cogerá el 75% del contenedor.

Por otro lado, usando `min-height: 100%` y `min-width: 100%` obligas a la imagen a que ocupe el 100% del contenedor, por lo tanto nunca se va a hacer responsive. Para pantallas muy pequeñas en cuanto a anchura, como el contenedor va a seguir midiendo 425px de altura la imagen se va a estirar hacia abajo.

El elemento `p` es un elemento `inline` por lo que necesita de la propiedad `display: block` para poder tener altura y anchura ya que los elementos `inline` no pueden tener estas propiedades.

Puedes comprobar que la imagen va a ser responsive para cualquier tipo de pantalla.

El código corregido quedaría así:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#hero {
  /*background-image: url("http://placehold.it/900x520");
  background-size: cover;*/
  height:425px;
  width:75%;
  background-color: red;
}

p{
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.image, .content{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/900x520" alt="Gato" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto no se comporta exactamente como `background-size:cover` ya que deja espacios en blanco (o en rojo) si la imagen no ocupa todo el `div` (es por eso que tiene el `min-width:100%` y `min-height:100%`). Lo que quiero evitar es precisamente eso, que queden espacios en blanco en el div contenedor

Comment: Vale, entendido. Déjame unos minutos para editar la respuesta.

Comment: Esto parece más `background-size: contain`, ¿es posible?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Mira a ver si esto es más acorde a lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por las alternativas, pero no son exactamente lo que busco. La primera opción que hiciste era más como `background-size:contain`, y ésta es como `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro De nada. La verdad que me costaba bastante saber lo que querías exactamente. Como puedes ver probé con `background-size: cover` para ver el comportamiento y al final fue el que a mi parecer más se parecía con el CSS que tu tenías. Me alegro de que la opción de @aldanux te haya servido :)